# Protractor in Jenkins > lib/atoms/error.js:108 > var template = new Error(this.message); ^ UnknownError: null

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, protractor

Bug report

I am working on integrating Protractor script with Jenkins and trying to run from it.

I am using grunt file to load the config file and package json for the plugins for grunt and jenkins. While running in Local my protractor test is working fine. But when committing to Jenkins and trying to run from it, throws the error

```
Output from running the test
grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy
├── file-sync-cmp@0.1.1
└── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)

grunt-cli@1.2.0 node_modules/grunt-cli
├── grunt-known-options@1.1.0
├── nopt@3.0.6 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── findup-sync@0.3.0 (glob@5.0.15)
└── resolve@1.1.7

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── which@1.0.9
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── exit@0.1.2
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.7.3)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.2, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.2)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3 (grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1, underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.2)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)

phantomjs@1.9.20 node_modules/phantomjs
├── progress@1.1.8
├── request-progress@2.0.1 (throttleit@1.0.0)
├── kew@0.7.0
├── hasha@2.2.0 (is-stream@1.1.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.1)
├── which@1.2.8 (isexe@1.1.2, is-absolute@0.1.7)
├── extract-zip@1.5.0 (debug@0.7.4, yauzl@2.4.1, mkdirp@0.5.0, concat-stream@1.5.0)
├── fs-extra@0.26.7 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, klaw@1.2.0, jsonfile@2.3.1, graceful-fs@4.1.4, rimraf@2.5.2)
└── request@2.67.0 (is-typedarray@1.0.0, aws-sign2@0.6.0, oauth-sign@0.8.2, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.3, caseless@0.11.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, combined-stream@1.0.5, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@5.2.0, mime-types@2.1.11, tough-cookie@2.2.2, form-data@1.0.0-rc4, bl@1.0.3, har-validator@2.0.6, http-signature@1.1.1, hawk@3.1.3)

grunt-contrib-jshint@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)
└── jshint@2.9.2 (strip-json-comments@1.0.4, console-browserify@1.1.0, exit@0.1.2, minimatch@2.0.10, shelljs@0.3.0, cli@0.6.6, htmlparser2@3.8.3, lodash@3.7.0)

grunt-ptor@1.0.10 node_modules/grunt-ptor
├── lodash.merge@4.4.0 (lodash._root@3.0.1, lodash.isplainobject@4.0.4, lodash.rest@4.0.3, lodash.keysin@4.1.4, lodash._baseclone@4.5.7)
├── yargs@4.7.1 (decamelize@1.2.0, camelcase@3.0.0, set-blocking@1.0.0, y18n@3.2.1, window-size@0.2.0, require-main-filename@1.0.1, lodash.assign@4.0.9, yargs-parser@2.4.0, string-width@1.0.1, os-locale@1.4.0, cliui@3.2.0, pkg-conf@1.1.2, read-pkg-up@1.0.1)
└── protractor@3.3.0 (jasminewd2@0.0.9, chalk@1.1.3, q@1.4.1, adm-zip@0.4.7, glob@6.0.4, optimist@0.6.1, saucelabs@1.0.1, jasmine@2.4.1, source-map-support@0.4.0, request@2.67.0, selenium-webdriver@2.52.0)

grunt-selenium-webdriver@0.2.482 node_modules/grunt-selenium-webdriver

grunt-protractor-runner@2.1.2 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner
├── split@0.3.3 (through@2.3.8)
├── through2@0.5.1 (xtend@3.0.0, readable-stream@1.0.34)
└── protractor@2.5.1 (jasminewd@1.1.0, jasminewd2@0.0.6, html-entities@1.1.3, q@1.0.0, minijasminenode@1.1.1, optimist@0.6.1, adm-zip@0.4.4, glob@3.2.11, jasmine@2.3.2, saucelabs@1.0.1, source-map-support@0.2.10, accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0, lodash@2.4.2, request@2.57.0, selenium-webdriver@2.47.0)

npm update
grunt test �[4mRunning "protractor:e2e" (protractor) task�[24m Starting selenium standalone server... [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver **Selenium standalone server started at http://10.87.23.55:40872/wd/hub /home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108 var template = new Error(this.message); ^ UnknownError: null at new bot.Error (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-**runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18) at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:109:9) at /home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:160:24 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1857:20) at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2448:25) at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:564:12) at Array.forEach (native) at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:553:15) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:130:15) at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7) From: Task: WebDriver.createSession() at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22) at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30) at [object Object].Builder.build (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:445:22) at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:38:7) at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:182:37) at /home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:263:21 at _fulfilled (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30) at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/jenkins/jobs/xxxxs/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13) at **/home/jenkins/jobs/xxx/workspace/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:573:44 [launcher] Process exited with error code 1 �[31m>> �[39m �[33mWarning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 1� Use --force to continue.�[39m
�[31mAborted due to warnings.�[39m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure``
Sending e-mails to: ``
Finished: FAILURE**
```

Steps to reproduce the bug
Commit the files to Jenkins

The URL you are running your tests against (if relevant)

Feature Request

Reasons for adopting new feature
Is this a breaking change? (How will this affect existing functionality)

Comment: can you check on you build machine, that you have node_modules/protractor/selenium/ folder with selenium standalone and chromedriver ? If you are just npm installing your package with protractor, these files are not included in protractor package.

Comment: I am having selenium standalone server and chrome driver in a seperate folder and calling them from config file.                          exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  chromeDriver: './SupportingDrivers/chromedriver_2.21',
  seleniumServerJar: './SupportingDrivers/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.0.jar',

Comment: Resolved the issue by downgrading the chromedriver version to 2.13.